# How can I generate random splatter shapes like these?

Tags: tiles, godot, image, tilesets

I am trying to make a tileset. I made some tiles by hand in GIMP using one of the included pencil shapes. I would like to automate the process. They need to fit in the square and have the features you see. Jagged edges and solid middles.

How would you generate shapes like these?

[image: tiles]

Comment: You might want to consider using [domain warping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22domain+warping%22) with a 2D noise function like Perlin noise or simplex noise.

Comment: @Kromster I think from the images we can infer that they are amorphous blobs that fit within a square (roughly equal in width and height), with noisy/speckled edges, a bit like spatter from a clogged spraypaint nozzle. Would you say those traits are enough to propose methods of generating similar shapes, or is there some aspect that's not clear enough from these examples?